# How do you get the value of a property in swipe view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have a `Swipeview` and I want to get the name of the dog if I swipe left

```
<swipeCardView:SwipeCardView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Frame CornerRadius="10"
                                       Padding="8"
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <AbsoluteLayout>
                                <AbsoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left" Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped" />
                                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Right" Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped_1" />
                                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Up" Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped_2" />
                                </AbsoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Image Source="{Binding dogImage}"
                                               Aspect="AspectFill"
                                               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,0.5,1,1"
                                               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
                                <Label FontSize="Large"
                                           WidthRequest="30"
                                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                                               TextColor="White"
                                               BackgroundColor="Black"
                                               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.1,0.95,250,30"
                                               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="{Binding dogGender}" />
                                                <Span Text=", " />
                                                <Span Text="{Binding breed_Name}" />
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                </AbsoluteLayout>
                            </Frame>

                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </swipeCardView:SwipeCardView.ItemTemplate>
```

I want to get the value of `Text="{Binding breed_Name}` when I swipe left in swipe view and saved it in a variable.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Command` instead of `Swiped` event and send it in `CommandParameter`

```
<swipeCardView:SwipeCardView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Frame CornerRadius="10"
                                       Padding="8"
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                         <AbsoluteLayout>
                            <AbsoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                 <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left"
                                          Command="{Binding LeftCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter={Binding breed_Name}"/>
                          ...
                                        <Label FontSize="Large"
                                        WidthRequest="30"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       TextColor="White"
                                       BackgroundColor="Black"
                                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.1,0.95,250,30"
                                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <Span Text="{Binding dogGender}" />
                                                    <Span Text=", " />
                                                    <Span Text="{Binding breed_Name}" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                     </Label>
                        </AbsoluteLayout>
...
```

```
public Command LeftCommand => new Command<string>(LeftSwipe);

void LeftSwipe(string parameter) 
{
    var variable = parameter; //= breed_Name
}
```